# How to use Global variable of one library to other library

Tags: c, linux, libraries

Can we declare a global variable in one library and assign some value and can we access or modify that global variable in different library?
I can only load library dynamically. (Using dlsym ).

Comment: you want to assassinate a value? 0o

Comment: I don't know how to assassin some value. But please don't do this. Let that value be alive.

Comment: maybe he thinks `free()` works as assassinator? :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

That variable must have external linkage, i.e. not `static` or `const`.

Once you loaded the library, call `dlsym` to get `void*` to that variable, cast it to its type and assign a value, e.g. `*(int*)dlsym(...) = 123`.